# New to Python and working on it to mess with JSON files

Tags: python, json

So I'm new to phython, and I was wondering on how I could modify(adding or subtracting) each individual "x" in one go.

```
            "Position": {
            "7,-5": {
                "id": "58",
                "y": -5,
                "x": 7
            },
            "2,-4": {
                "id": "183",
                "y": -4,
                "x": 2
            },
            "-4,-1": {
                "id": "190",
                "y": -1,
                "x": -4
            }
```

I tried doing

```
import json
with open ('position.txt', 'r+') as f:
    position_data = json.load(f)
    position_data['Position']['x'] = +1

 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

This is what I want

```
            "Position": {
            "7,-5": {
                "id": "58",
                "y": -5,
                "x": 8
            },
            "2,-4": {
                "id": "183",
                "y": -4,
                "x": 3
            },
            "-4,-1": {
                "id": "190",
                "y": -1,
                "x": -3
            }
```

I'm not sure on how to go from here.  Please advice.

Comment: I can't be sure how this is constructed, you don't have the same number of opening and closing brackets. Could you please fix that.

Comment: Is that your real data? It's missing some curly braces.

Comment: Please provide a short, **complete** JSON sample. Please copy-paste it into your question, do not retype it. Please make the sample as short as possible, and copy-paste the **entire** sample.

Comment: No, @BryanOakley, it isn't. His real data includes a list, according to his error message. But the data in his question doesn't.

Comment: `position_data['Position']['x'] = +1` gives an error because that's not the structure of the data. To get the first "x" you need this: `position_data['Position']['7,-5']['x']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
for key in position_data['Position'].keys():
    position_data['Position'][key]['x'] += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for value in position_data['Position'].values():
    value['x'] += 1
```

Use `itervalues` in Python 2 for better efficiency.

Demo (since I got downvoted without explanation):

```
from pprint import pprint

position_data = {
    "Position": {
        "7,-5": {
            "id": "58",
            "y": -5,
            "x": 7
        },
        "2,-4": {
            "id": "183",
            "y": -4,
            "x": 2
        },
        "-4,-1": {
            "id": "190",
            "y": -1,
            "x": -4
        }
    }
}

pprint(position_data)

for value in position_data['Position'].values():
    value['x'] += 1

pprint(position_data)
```

Output:

```
{'Position': {'-4,-1': {'id': '190', 'x': -4, 'y': -1},
              '2,-4': {'id': '183', 'x': 2, 'y': -4},
              '7,-5': {'id': '58', 'x': 7, 'y': -5}}}
{'Position': {'-4,-1': {'id': '190', 'x': -3, 'y': -1},
              '2,-4': {'id': '183', 'x': 3, 'y': -4},
              '7,-5': {'id': '58', 'x': 8, 'y': -5}}}
```